# Gson Single Key Value

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

What's the simplest/fastest way to deserialize a single key value element with Gson library on Android? Server sends something like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Field1": "Value1",
            "Field2": "Value2",
            "Field3": "Value3"
        },
        {
            "Field1": "Value1",
            "Field2": "Value2",
            "Field3": "Value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need to "enter" data value (the array) and then bind the values to a model. Ok with the second part, but I'm missing the first. Should I use an HashMap, JsonParser or something?

```
JsonElement dataElem = new JsonParser().parse(response);

String data = dataElem.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsString();

bundle.putParcelableArray("models", gson.fromJson(data, Model[].class));
```

Am i near the right solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
String data = dataElem.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsString();
```

You don't want a `String`, you want the actual `JsonElement` from the parse tree:

```
JsonElement je = dataElem.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
```

Then your deserialization to an array of your `Model` will work:

```
bundle.putParcelableArray("models", gson.fromJson(je, Model[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can parse it as

**1. Without Model class**

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(Your_JSON_String).getAsJsonObject().get("data");
Type typeOfCollection = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType();
List<Map<String, String>> dataList = gson.fromJson(element, typeOfCollection);
```

**2. With Model class.**

```
public class Model {
    private List<Map<String,String>> data;
}

 Model model= gson.fromJson(Your_JSON_String, Model.class)
```